# Теряется байт при передаче через serial порт

Tags: python, pyqt5, serial, com-порт

Суть проблемы: При передаче строки байт через `serial` порт, теряется 1 байт. Причем в `ser.write(msg)` уходит правильная строчка `'\xff\xff\x00\x00'`, а принимается уже всего 3 байта `'\xff\x00\x00'`.

Подробное описание проблемы: Пишу приложение (Клиент) на PyQt5 которое общается через виртуальный `Com2Com` мост с написанным мною же эмулятором реального устройства (Сервер). Клиент запускает поток, который слушает `Serial` порт. Сервер тоже слушает `Serial` порт через мост. Опустим протокол обмена данными, все работает, но в определенный момент, после нажатия кнопки в Клиенте, к Серверу посылается запрос на выдачу изображения, выглядит он так `':G\r'`. Сервер парсит пришедшую команду и отсылает разрешение будущего изображения в формате `':g1024&768\r'`. Пришедшее изображение парсится, вычисляется количество байт которое будет необходимо считать для построения изображения (каждый пиксель в `grayscale` формате, то есть это число от 0 до 255), буду брать самое простое - 2 x 2 пикселя (следовательно получить надо 4 байта). После этого, Клиент отсылает Серверу команду `':F\r'` и переводится из абстрактного режима чтения команд `com_mode = 0` в режим принятия изображений `com_mode = 1` - слушает порт до получения необходимого количества байт. Вот код:

```
    if com_mode:
    try:
        byte = self.ser.read()
        print [byte]
        img_str += byte
        if len(img_str) >= 1:
            print len(img_str)
            self.img_loading.emit(len(img_str))
            if len(img_str) == img_prbar:
                com_mode = 0
                self.img_rcvd.emit()
    except serialutil.SerialException:
        self.com_conn_err_signal.emit('Error. Cant read IMAGE from serial port.')
```

Сигнал `img_loading` для прогрессбара, на него не обращайте внимание.
А вот дальше - сравниваем длину полученного сообщения с необходимой. Если все байты пришли, переводим поток в режим принятия команд и генерируем сигнал. Так вот, когда Сервер получает команду `':F\r'` он генерирует и отсылает строку байт:

```
def img_sender(self):
    global img_resp
    img_resp = True
    img_str = b''
    img_b_num = w_img * h_img
    for i in range(img_b_num):
        if i < img_b_num / 2:
            img_str += pack('B', 255)
        else:
            img_str += pack('B', 0)
    self.comPortListenerThread.send(img_str)
```

При передаче в порт, я вывожу в консоль значения:

```
def send(self, msg):
    global img_resp
    if com_conn and not img_resp:
        self.ser.write(msg + '\r')
    elif com_conn and img_resp:
        print len(msg)
        print [msg]
        self.ser.write(msg)
        img_resp = False
```

так вот, эти самые

```
        print len(msg)
        print [msg]
```

выдают следующее:

```
4
['\xff\xff\x00\x00']
```

все хорошо - 2 белых пикселя, 2 черных, однако, в Клиенте, происходит какая-то чертовщина. `print [byte]` и `print len(img_str)` из первого куска кода выводят следующее:

```
['\xff']
1
['\x00']
2
['\x00']
3
```

И все, молчок, прогрессбар показывает 75%! Если еще раз нажать на кнопку, то опять отправляется команда `':F\r'`, на которую Сервер отвечает тем же самым `':g2&2\r'` и в `img_str` дописывается `:`, которое, в последствие переводится в число `58`:

```
[':']
4
[[255   0]
 [  0  58]]
```

Что делать - не представляю, куда девается байт? Как с этим бороться? 
Причем, если при генерации изображения сделать запас в 1 лишний байт, то все путем ... как так-то?

Comment: Скорее всего проблемы с многопоточностью. Поставил 1 usleep и все стало работать ...Надо с Mutex разобраться.

Comment: мне кажется  flush не хватает